# in WP_Query get_current_user_id( ) is not returning data for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

i want to fetch data from my custom post type (note) so that's why i'm using WP_Query() , it's working fine but when i want to fetch data only related to the user logged in so i'm using author => get_current_user_id() now my web page showing nothing

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'author'  => get_current_user_id(), // before using this it was working fine 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'note',
     );

$userNotes = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($userNotes->have_posts()): while ($userNotes->have_posts()) : $userNotes->the_post(); ?>

   <li>
      <input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
      <span class="edit-note"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</span>
      <span class="delete-note"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</span>
      <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
     </li>


<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();

        ?>
```

it's showing nothing (blank)

my note custom post type

// Note Post Type

```
register_post_type('note',[
'show_in_rest' => true,
'supports' => ['title','editor'],
'public'    => false,
'show_ui'   =>true,
'labels'    => [
    'name'=>'Notes',
    'add_new_item' =>'Add New Note',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Note',
    'all_items' =>'All Notes',
    'singular_name' =>'Note'
],
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
```

]);

```
<?php

  if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect(esc_url(site_url('/')));
    exit;
  }
  get_header();

    pageBanner();
     ?>



    <div class="container container--narrow page-section">
      <ul class="min-list link-list" id="my-notes">
        <?php 


    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_type' => 'note',
        'author' => get_current_user_id()
    );

    $userNotes = new WP_Query($args);
    while($userNotes->have_posts()) : $userNotes->the_post();
    ?>
     <li>
              <input class="note-title-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
              <span class="edit-note"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</span>
              <span class="delete-note"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</span>
              <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
            </li>

    <?php  

    endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <?php 

  get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','post_type' => 'note','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php get_title(); ?>"></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;

endif;
```

Comment: thanks for your input but it didn't workout , the code that i wrote in my question in the query if i change post type 'note' to anything else (program, professor) it works fine  , i think the problem is in my note custom post type

Comment: @ajaymeena there might be capabilities issue for your custom post type "note". Check current user role then check that role capabilities it seems like it don't have read access to note.

Comment: @RahatHameed i think so , but i am doing exactly the way i did for all custom post types  others working fine , can you please tell me how can i send you my code in stackoverflow comments,  i'm new here thanks in advanced

Comment: Install membership plugin then check update capabilities of particular role which is assigned to your author.  [Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)